# Can I post multiple objects to a REST service but only one as @RequestParams and how to call it from PostMan

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

So I have a method that looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/endpoint")
void  myMethod(Student student, @RequestBody Teacher teacher)
{
    //need to be able to access student.getName();
     //Need to be able to access teacher.getName();
}
```

This is given, I can not change this.
Question how do I call this method from PostMan.

I use Post request :
localhost:8080/endpoint
and in the body, I select : raw
and JSON
but I can not figure what I am doing from here, as when I put json I ont see values in the student object it is null, not sure how to create a correct json,

```
class Student {
  String id;
  String nameStudent;
}

сlass Teacher {
  String id, 
  String nameTeacher;
}
```

Comment: doing from here create a correct json, as when I put json see values in the student object

Comment: sorry K.Nicholas I dont understand your comment, I am not sure how to create a correct json,

Comment: If you cannot modify the controller method, then no, you cannot do this.  At a minimum, you would need to annotate Student also with @RequestBody, but you'd have to write a custom deserializer even to pull this off.  Ideally, your method would contain a single RequestBody, perhaps a DTO that contains both the teacher and student.  Given the way your model looks, there's no way to associate a teacher with a student.  I would push back on the "I can't change this", part.

Comment: I have an existing code which works at the moment, and I am simply trying to send a JSON request, hence I said I can not not change. as this is how it is currently set up

Comment: Try to add Student's fields as query parameters. So: id and nameStudent should be in query parameters instead of request body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HTTP POST can only have ONE body. As commenters have indicated, but I will spell out to provide clarity, you have the following two options:

Create a class which combines Student & Teacher and use that as the request body:

```
class Payload {
    Student student;
    Teacher teacher;
}

@PostMapping("/endpoint")
void  myMethod(@RequestBody Payload payload) {
    Student student = payload.student;
    Teacher teacher = payload.teacher;
```

JSON payload for Postman:

```
{
    "student": {
        "id": "abc",
        "name": "A Student name"
    },
    "teacher": {
        "id": "def",
        "name": "A Teacher name"
    }
}
```

The other option is to pass though the Student attributes as query parameters:

```
@PostMapping("/endpoint")
void  myMethod(@RequestParam studentId, @RequestParam studentName, @RequestBody Teacher teacher) {
    Student student = new Student(studentId, studentName);
```

And the `studentId` & `studentName` must be submitted as parameters from Postman.